# How to get selected value from JQuery Dropdownlist in View to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a program that plots bus routes on a map using asp.net MVC and Bing Maps. I want to be able to change what bus route the map shows by using a drop down list to select the routes name, and passing that name value as a String back to a method in the controller which will query the database with it

The relevant code is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BusRouteNames", new SelectList())

<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="BusRoute">Select a Bus Route</label>
        <select name="busroute" id="busroute">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Stop 1</option>
            <option value="2">Stop 2</option>
            <option value="3">Stop 3</option>
            <option value="4">Stop 4</option>
            <option value="5">Stop 5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" title="Calculate" value="Calculate Route" onclick="location.href=''" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I thought I could do this with a `@Url.Action()` method to do this, but I've read you can't request JavaScript variables this way, so I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested approach. It would be helpful to be passing a model to your cshtml view. Then you can create the dropdown list and handle selections through the model and controller.

Such as:

```
// update your model
public class YourModel {
    public class List<SelectListItem> BusRoutes { get; set; }
    public string SelectedBusRoute { get; set; }
}

// in your controller get method
public ActionResult<YourModel> Get(string route = null)
{
    var model = new YourModel();
    // add your data
    model.BusRoutes = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Stop 2", Value = "2" },
        // add rest...
    };
    // set selected value
    model.SelectedBusRoute = route ?? "2";
    return View(model);
}

// in YourModel.cshtml
@model YourModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Get", "YourController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBusRoute, Model.BusRoutes, "-- Select Route--");
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>

}
@* Generate your map using the Model.SelectedBusRoute value *@
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a simple question, but can you pass more than 1 thing through a model at a time? Because I'm already passing through a different model to this view for something else related to the route.

Comment: I should clarify, I'm already passing through a `List<>` of another model class. If I was to make a new class, can I pass and populate them both?